# converting K-SAT clause to a p-in-L-SAT equation

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reductions

Given a generic K-SAT instance $S$ with $n$ boolean variables.

Is it possible to convert a clause of this instance into an equivalent p-in-L SAT system of equations such that the number of new clauses introduced is more than the number of new variables introduced?

Comment: I think this answer provides such a reduction. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/42223/45276

Comment: @rus9384 Thank you. But the $(x, x', F_1)$ and $(\neg x, \neg x', F_1)$ is essentially introducing a dummy variable $(F_1)$ that will always have to be FALSE and I am trying to avoid such tricks (dummy variables and clauses)...